# How can I get image list and download these images from public-shared-gallery-link by using Dropbox SDK?

Tags: ruby, download, carousel, dropbox-api, imagelist

I want to get the image list and download those images from a Dropbox's public-shared-link, which I get it from my client.
I'm using Dropbox SDK for ruby and only find the methods to manage files via my Dropbox account, such as put_file, get_file, get_file_and_metadata, get_chunked_uploader, upload and so on.
Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Dropbox API v1 has an endpoint that allows you to retrieve metadata about shared links:

https://www.dropbox.com/developers-v1/core/docs#metadata-link

Dropbox API v2 has a similar pair of endpoints that allows you to retrieve metadata and file content, respectively, from shared links:

https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#sharing-get_shared_link_metadata
https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#sharing-get_shared_link_file

Unfortunately, none of these are currently implemented in the Ruby SDK. You can call them directly though, or modify the Ruby SDK to do so.

Comment: Thanks @Greg so much.